# Saving locally javascript changes

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

Im trying to figure out if it's possible and how I could save changes made to a page using javascript to a browser.

For example: I have a toggle which hides a menu. So I hide my menu and leave the page. When I visit this page again, I want that menu to remain hidden. As of now, any changes I make using Javascript disappear once I leave the session or refresh

Comment: You should use cookies.

Comment: @DC_: If the server doesn't need access to it and `localStorage` is available, `localStorage` is a better idea than cookies: cookies will be sent to the server on every request, so putting stuff in cookies when the server won't need it and there's an alternative is discouraged.

Comment: I need to use localStorage for this solution, at least that's what the professor wants. It's an HTML5 class but the example he showed in class doesn't really apply to my site and im pretty confused. The examples I've seen are just using a text box with a key/value pair and saving that information where as my set has multiple styles changes the prof wants saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like you are thinking, no.  There is no "remember this page state" flag or anything.

However, there is a way to store *data*.  On modern browsers, [you can use `localStorage`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) to persist some choice or data the user makes.  Then when the page is loaded, your javascript can read that data and then configure the page around.

For example:

```
$('#hide-stuff-button').click(function() {
  $('#stuff').hide();
  localStorage.hidden = true;
});

if (localStorage.hidden) {
  $('#stuff').hide();
}
```

That script does 2 things. It saves some preference when you click a button, and when the page loads, it reads the saved state and does something to the page.

Comment: From what I can see, what you are doing is using the localStorage as a boolean to determine the toogle state. I don't think this will work for me because the changes available on my page have more than two states. http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html 
In the side menu for example I have a change background option with maybe 9 different backgrouns, the video player is using a random color generator so the colors have infinite options... your solution however would work for the wideScreen option because it's simply hiding and hiding the sidebar

Comment: @Batman It is jQuery, which I used for brevity.  And this was simply an example.  You can store any kind of data you want, and then read it back to bootup the page however you need.

Comment: I don't have time to fix it (and the edit might be too big to "preserve the author's intent"), but the above is fairly misleading, because it makes it look like what's stored in the boolean. `localStorage` only stores **strings**. So while the above works just fine, a refinement later that might set `localStorage.hidden = false;` would fail to work as expected, because that's really `localStorage.hidden = "false"` which is a truthy value, fooling `if (localStorage.hidden)`. Recommend clarifying the string nature of `localStorage`.